# Make custom web application in _layouts aware of sub-sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an SharePoint 2010 web site which has different sub-sites and I have custom (just ASP.NET) web application deployed to `_layouts` directory.

What is the best way to add this application to particular sub-site so application itself will know where it is located?

For example I have

- http://example.com/ - root site
- http://example.com/site1 - subsite
- http://example.com/_layouts/mywebapp - my web application

Now I'm adding this application to sub-site as Page Viewer (iframe in nature)

I want to make my application aware of concrete sub-site.